# Uniform Continuity of functions

Tags: calculus

I need the general mindset how to show that those functions are uniformly continuous:
$f(x)=x^2/(1+x)$ where $x\in[0,\infty)$
and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}\sin(1/x)$ where $x\in(0,\infty)$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why the word 'uniform' in the title?

Comment: You want to show that they are continuous or uniformly continuous?

Comment: @caffeinemachine at those intervals.

Comment: @user3708158 : You seem to have misunderstood caffeinemachine's comment.  A function can be continuous on an interval, i.e. continuous at every point in the interval, without being uniformly continuous on the interval. Your question asks about proving that they are continuous, but your subject line refers to uniform continuity.  Just what is intended in the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

For $\frac{x^2}{1+x}$, let any $\epsilon > 0$. Allow $\delta \equiv \epsilon > \delta_1 > 0$,  and $x,y \equiv (x + \delta_1) \in [0,\infty)$:

$$|y-x|=\delta_1 < \delta \implies |\frac{y^2}{1+y} - \frac{x^2}{1+x}|=|\frac{\delta_1(x^2 + 2x + \delta_1 x + \delta_1)}{x^2+2x+ \delta_1 x + \delta_1 + 1}| < |\frac{\delta_1(x^2 + 2x + \delta_1 x + \delta_1)}{x^2+2x+ \delta_1 x + \delta_1}| = \delta_1 < \delta = \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

As @idm mentioned in his answer. There are no true mindsets in proving uniform continuity. However, in most cases there are two important results:

1. If a function is Lipschitz, then it is uniformly continuous.
2. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Back to the given functions. $f(x)$ is Lipschitz so uniformly continuous.

$g(x)$ is Lipschitz away from $0$, for example on $[1,\infty)$, and can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,2]$. So that $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous on each interval.

Note that $[0,2]\cap [1,\infty)=[1,2]\neq 0$. This implies $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to show the uniform continuity. But in your case, for the first one:

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\frac{x(x+2)}{(x+1)^2}$$

and so,

$$\forall x\in[0,1], 0\leq f'(x)< 1.$$

Then, by the mean value theorem, your function is Lipschitz, therefore continous. Indeed, if the derivate of a function is bounded, the function is Lipschitz and so the function is uniform continuous.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I erase this part. But do you agree that if $g$ would be uniformly continuous on $[\alpha, b]$ for all $\alpha\in]0,b]$, then $g$ would be uniformly continuous on $]0,b]$ ?

Comment: Same idea with what you erased, that's not correct. Consider function $\frac1x$.